# Is it valid to use formatted I/O operators for binary files?

Tags: c++, unicode, fstream, binaryfiles

On line, #12 below I have seen some people opening the file in binary mode and then doing `<<` to write to the file. Is this valid?

```
 1 int main()
 2 {
 3     std::ofstream testFile;
 4 
 5     testFile.open("file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
 6 
 7     std::wstring text = L"Привет";
 8 
 9     std::string outtext = to_utf8(text);
10 
11     // Is this valid?
12     testFile << outtext;
13 
14     testFile.close();
15 
16     return 0;
17 }
```

Any problems if I avoid opening the file in binary mode for writing UTF-8 strings writing?

Comment: You mostly want to open in binary mode. Text mode is an abomination to be avoided unless you understand exactly what it does and why you want it.